# List Sibling Pages By Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, tagging

I'm trying to make a list of all sibling (sub)pages of a parent page. That's easy enough.
But I've tagged each sibling child page, and I would like to organize my list like so:

```
Term 1
  - Child/Sibling Page 1
  - Child/Sibling Page 2
  - Child/Sibling Page 4
Term 2
  - Child/Sibling Page 3
Term 4
  - Child/Sibling Page 5
  - Child/Sibling Page 6
  - Child/Sibling Page 7
```

I need this list to appear on both the parent page and each sibling child page. Here's what I have so far to list all the sibling pages:

```
<?php if($post->post_parent): ?>
<?php $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($children) { ?>
<ul class="subpage-list">
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. The block after the condition `if($post->post_parent): ... ` finds all the siblings of the current post while for top level (no post_parent) posts you find the children of the current post. Is this intended? When you say **"sibling (sub)pages of a parent page"** that's a bit confusing. I see you want to organize the retrieved pages based on their associated tags, but we need more information. Can you give a overview of how the pages and the tags are related? Note that a post can have multiple tags but you seem to want to put each page under only one tag.

Comment: Excellent questions. I'll see if I can explain myself better.
I have a parent page, PARENT
and that page has several child pages. Those child pages are all "siblings" of each other.
So, if you're on the Parent page, I want to list all the children by tag (if the page has multiple tags, it can show up under multiple tag headings). And, if you're on a child page, I want to show that same list of sibling pages, also organized by tag. Does that clarify any?
Also, my code above does list all the child/sibling pages correctly, but what I can't figure out is how to iterate through the list of tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have come up with an answer. This code may be a little rough, but as far as I can tell it works as needed:

```
<?php 
if($post->post_parent):
  $postparent = $post->post_parent;
else: 
  $postparent = $post->ID;
endif; 

$nextTagThumb='-1';
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($postparent);
foreach ($tags as $tag) :

  if ($tags) {
    $what_tag = $tags[($nextTagThumb+'1')]->term_id;
    $tag_title = $tags[($nextTagThumb+'1')]->name;
    echo '<div class="Saving_sare">'. "\n";
    echo '<h4>'.$tag_title.'</h4>'. "\n";
    echo '<ul>'. "\n";
    $args=array(
      'tag__in' => array($what_tag),
      'post__not_in' => array($postparent),
      'showposts'=>100,
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile;
    }
    echo '</ul>'. "\n";
    echo '</div>'. "\n";
    wp_reset_query();
    $nextTagThumb = ($nextTagThumb+1);
  }
endforeach; 
?>
```